# How can I transform a large JSON file at build time with webpack?

Tags: json, webpack

An external tool gives me a large JSON file with a lot of useless information for us in the frontend.

We have a code like that (simplified for this example)

```
import json from 'my.json'

export const listOfJsonName = json.map(data => data.name)
```

Because we use just the name, and that the list of names is 5 to 6 times smaller than the original JSON, I would like to have in my final bundle *only* the list of names.

ie. I would like `json.map(data => data.name)` to happen at build time, to ensure we don't load the complete JSON.

Is there a way to do that with webpack?

(Obviously we could modify the file *before* and import the modified file, and we may end up doing that, but I'm interested to know what we can do with webpack anyway :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [modify-source-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/artemirq/modify-source-webpack-plugin) for this task.

```
  plugins: [
    new ModifySourcePlugin({
      rules: [
        {
          test: /my\.json$/,
          modify: (src, filename) =>
            JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(src).map(data => data.name))
        }
      ],
    })
  ],
```